# Tabela Pivo para 3 Tabelas Laravel

Tags: laravel

A minha duvida seria como exibir dados da tabela em um relacionamento many to many com mais de duas tabelas relacionadas:

Ex: Tabela principal VENDA
Tabela PIVO VENDA_DETALHE (onde vai idvenda/idproduto/idcentrocusto)
Tabela PRODUTO
Tabela CENTROCUSTO

---

**MODEL VENDA**

```
public function produto()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Produto::class,'venda_produto_centrocusto');
}

public function centrocusto()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(CentroCusto::class,'venda_produto_centrocusto');
}
```

**MODEL PRODUTO**

```
public function venda()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Venda::class,'venda_produto_centrocusto');
}
```

**MODEL CENTRO DE CUSTO**

```
public function venda()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Venda::class,'venda_produto_centrocusto');
}
```

**CONTROLLER**
    public function create()
    {
    $vendas= Venda::with('produto','centrocusto')->get();

```
return view('venda.pedido.create',compact('vendas'));
}
```

**NA VIEW**

```
foreach ($vendas as $venda) {
    foreach ($produtos as produto) {

         foreach ($produtos as produto) {
        // Aqui quero rodar os produtos e o centro de custo dessa venda;
         Esta dando erro aqui, ela esta trazendo todos os centros de custos

        }
    }
}
```

**ERRO CAMPO CENTRO DE CUSTO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Chegou a dar uma olhada na sessão **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns** da [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) ?

Comment: Estou lendo, mas ainda não consegui implementar, esta dando erro.

Comment: Então você poderia colocar a parte do código que está dando erro na sua pergunta (só a parte com erro, o código todo não. Por favor :D ). E aproveita e tenta explicar o que você já tentou e que erro está mostrando.
Assim vai ter mais gente pra te ajudar.

Comment: Para editar a pergunta é só clicar no botão editar (é só para você não postar suas dúvidas aqui no comentário)

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria você mostrar o erro, mas vou supor que o erro seja a forma que você faz o relacionamento pela view, e note que você deixou de colocar o $ para declarar o produto.

```
foreach ($vendas as $venda) {
    foreach ($produtos as produto) {
```

Corrige para essa forma, e vê se foi solucionado seu problema:

```
foreach ($vendas as $venda) {
    foreach ($venda->produto as $produto) {
```

Comment: Eu fiz assim

foreach ($vendas as $venda) {
    $produtos = $venda->produtos;
    foreach ($produtos as $produto) {

Comment: Esta retornando os produtos certinho o problema e pra retornar o centrodecusto. Quando dou um foreache nele ele vem duplicado, se tento acessar ele direto da pau.

Comment: Tentando dessa forma ainda sai duplicado?
foreach ($vendas as $venda) 
 foreach ($venda->produtos as produto) 
    foreach ($produto->centrocusto as $centrocusto)
Edita seu post inicial e mostra o erro para ficar mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Fiz esse exemplo usando solicitação ao invéz de venda. Centro de Custo nao esta dentro de Produto esta dentro de Solicitação ou Venda no caso assim como produto entendeu?

Comment: Tenta dividir a relação para vários um para muitos, cria um novo model e faça a relação: Venda hasMany novoModel. Produto hasMany novoModel. CentroCusto hasMany novoModel.  novoModel belongsTo Venda. novoModel belongsTo Produto. novoModel belongsTo CentroCusto. E faça o foreach.
da uma conferida na documentação de um para muitos: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: OK vou tentar, e posto o resultado